# Можно ли на форуме организовать раздел для обсуждения средств художественной выразительности?

Tags: обсуждение, предложение

Иногда на форуме задаются такие вопросы, но они являются **исключением**. С другой стороны, любовь и понимание языка — это не только умение находить подлежащее и сказуемое или правильно расставлять запятые. Образно говоря, названные темы —  это только **скучные гаммы, но не сама музыка**.

Наши пользователи **не мотивированы на такую любовь**, поэтому начинают не любить язык еще с детского школьного возраста, о вот в раннем детстве они наслаждаются языком — каждым словом и каждой фразой (понаблюдайте за любым ребенком, чтобы убедиться в этом). Язык помогает  понимать прекрасное, учит любви и сочувствию.

Но мы почему-то считаем, что единственное достойное занятие для филологов и энтузиастов  языка — это **не русская речь сама по себе**, а только правописание и базовая школьная грамматика. Даже вопросы по стилистике обсуждаются скорее на пользовательском уровне (мне кажется, что так правильно, а так неправильно).

Так может найдется на сайте маленький уголок для любителей художественного слова, ну хотя бы для начала **в виде метки** "выразительные средства языка"? Для обсуждения можно будет предлагать только конкретные вопросы по отдельным предложениям, причем семантика должна обязательно связываться с формой, но ни в коем случае не обсуждаться отдельно.

**Почему возник такой вопрос?** Это под впечатлением от недавней темы со стихотворным текстом. Спрашивали, что поставить — запятую, тире или запятую и тире. А я обратила внимание на  форму стиха. Само содержание тоже заинтересовало, но форма была не очень удачной, **вот чуть-чуть бы подправить, а как?**

Заинтересовало, да, но обсудить оказалось не с кем. К тому же обсуждение выходило за рамки заданного вопроса.

[https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/461200/Запятая-и-тире-в-авторском-стихотворении](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/461200/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%B8-%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B5-%D0%B2-%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%85%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8)

Comment: Даже на Мете минусы ставят?!

Comment: @АлександрСтрелец если это предложение, то участники имеют право выражать своё мнение о нём с помощью системы голосования.